# Access Join without Double Counting

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables. One with amounts in quarterly increments, the other with amounts in annual increments. I want to join the two and sum FEES and COUNTS without double counting.

```
Table 1         
CLM_NUM Year    Quarter FEES
1234    2016    1       100
1234    2016    2       100
1234    2016    3       100
1234    2016    4       100

Table 2         
CLM_NUM Year    COUNT   
1234    2016    10  

Desired Result:         
CLM_NUM Year    FEES    COUNT
1234    2016    400     10
```

However, my query causes the counts to be counted four times resulting in 40, not 10.
How do I resolve this?

```
    SELECT Table1.CLM_NUM, Table1.YEAR, Sum(Table1.FEES) AS SumOfFEES, 
    Sum(Table2.COUNT) AS SumOfCOUNT
    FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.CLM_NUM = Table2.CLM_NUM) AND  (Table1.YEAR = Table2.YEAR) 
    GROUP BY Table1.CLM_NUM, Table1.YEAR;
```

Comment: Can there be more than 1 column with the same CLM_NUM in your table 2?

Comment: Table 2 has only one field called CLM_NUM. Do you mean row? Table 2 has one row per CLM_NUM and Year combination.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant row. do you want one result per CLM_NUM or one per CLM_NUM/Year?

Comment: per CLM_NUM/Year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub-query. The SUM in the sub-query means it would work even if table 2 wasn't yearly (i.e. there were more rows per CLM_NUM/Year key).

```
SELECT 
    t1.clm_num, 
    t1.year,
    sum(t1.fees),
    (SELECT 
        sum(t2.count) 
     FROM 
        Table2 t2
     WHERE t1.CLM_NUM = t2.CLM_NUM
       AND t1.Year = t2.Year
     GROUP BY 
        t2.CLM_NUM, t2.Year
    ) AS SumOfCount
FROM 
    Table1 t1
GROUP BY 
    t1.CLM_NUM, t1.Year
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Quick question: if I want to sum multiple fields from table2, do I need to do multiple subroutines or can I add the multiple fields to my select statement in the subroutine? I tried doing the latter and it didn't work for me, but when I limited my select to a single field, it worked.

Comment: You can't return multiple columns from that sub-query as I've written it. If you want to aggregate multiple columns from the second table, you can join to the "sub-query" from which you can select multiple aggregate values (e.g. sum(t2.Count), sum(t2.SomethingElse)). The alternative is to repeat the sub-query for each column you want to aggregate, but for large data sets it might not perform well.

Answer (score 0):

if access doesnt have max, use first
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7ec1d/1

```
select t1.clm_num, t1.year,sum(t1.fees),max(t2.count)
from Table1 t1 inner join 
Table2 t2 on t2.clm_num = t1.clm_num and  (t1.YEAR = t2.YEAR) 
GROUP BY t1.CLM_NUM, t1.YEAR
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I believe this solution works given there is only one row per clm_num and year on table2. Is there a more general solution, if for instance, table 2 was on a bi-annual basis where I couldn't simply take the max? I could separately summarize each table to one row per claim and then do the join, but I am wondering if there is an easy way to do it all in one query. Thanks!

Comment: your group is still by clm_num and by .YEAR

your taking the max of table2, which one be only one record for that relationship1.

if you really want the problem solved , use an online database we can work on together, insert ALL the data that you can for see, and we can test and fiddle with it

Comment: fyi this is all in one query

Comment: the max is only executing on the distinct record, so its not doing the max that you think of.  Unless your data that i mocked up is going to be different.  Please mock you data using sqlfiddle.com so the user can sufficiently answer your question, fyi the users sql above who answered after me, is also correct, assuming your data